# How to decode SAML Response and get the attribute values sent by Idp in PHP

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, opensaml

I am implementing SAML Single Sign-On and using idp initiated method for login request. After login it redirect users on the login url defined on the request with the base64 encoded SAML Response.

Now, I have extract to this response, validate it and get the attribute value sent by the Idp like email address, name etc.

I have decoded from base64 and got the following XML. This XML have encrypted Signature, CipherData, Certificate etc.. but don't know how to validate and decode/extract the attribute values so that we can use it further.

I search for it and fond the [online tool](https://www.samltool.com/attributes.php)  which is decoding it, by providing the private key. I tried it and got the attribute values.

The same thing I have to do in our application using PHP and have to use this attributes value. If any one have did the same thing and can put some light on it then it will be really appreciated.

Pleas Check the SAML Response below.

```
<samlp:Response Version="2.0" ID="vafmraxdfkermx" IssueInstant="2015-07-31T07:26:00.180Z" Destination="http://domain.com/saml/SSO" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">MI-TEST-SAML2-EntityID</saml:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#DLSr8z03t7WZ-F7ZFwbxUw91vQF">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>gnvnDwu/eDBpLnPtiaHeOI7UCD4=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
        Signature Value
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
                Certifivate Contents
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
</samlp:Status>
<saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey>
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>CIPHER VALUE</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>CIPHER CONTETNS</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</saml:EncryptedAssertion>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online tool that you used is based on the OneLogin's PHP SAML Toolkit [1]. I implemented both.

Read the documentation. The processResponse and the getAttributes do what you want.

[1] https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml

Comment: Thank for reply, After posting question I also found the same thing, It works perfect, I have completed the functionality using the same.   https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, it may be easier to let existing code handle all SAML for you. For PHP, you have SimpleSAMLphp which can be configured as a service provider.

SimpleSamlPHP will generate the metadata for you and consume SAML assertions and validate them. Attributes can be retrieved using a function. See [SimpleSAMLphp Service Provider QuickStart](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LightSAML](https://packagist.org/packages/lightsaml/lightsaml) to receive the encoded SAML Response directly from http request, de-serialize it into a data model, and decrypt it. Here's an example on how to receive a SAML message from HTTP request http://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-receive-SAML-message/ and here's an example on how to decrypt an Assertion http://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-decrypt-Assertion/